# Transporting with data from S3 amazon to local server

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to import data from S3 and using the described below script (which I sort of inherited). It's a bit long...The problem is I kept receiving following output:

```
The config profile (importer) could not be found
```

I am not a bash person-so be gentle, please. It seemed there are some credentials missing or something else is wrong with configuration of "importer" on local machine.
In S3 configs(the console) - there is a user with the same name, which, according to permissions can perform access the bucket and download data. 
I have tried changing access keys in amazon console for the user and creating file, named "credentials" in `home/.aws`(there was no `.aws` folder in home dir by default-created it), including the new keys in the file, tried upgrading AWS CLI with pip - nothing helped
Then I have modified the "credentials", placing [importer] as profile name, so it looked like:

```
[importer]
aws_access_key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret+key = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Appears, that I have gone through the "miss-configuration":

```
A client error (InvalidAccessKeyId) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

And here's the part, where I am stuck...I placed the keys, I have obtained from the amazon into that config file. Double checked...Any suggestions? I can't produce anymore keys-aws quota/user. Below is part of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "\n$0 started at: `date`"
incomming='/Database/incomming'

IFS='
';

mkdir -p ${incomming}
echo "syncing files from arrivals bucket to ${incomming} incomming folder"
echo aws --profile importer \
    s3  --region eu-west-1 sync s3://path-to-s3-folder ${incomming}
aws --profile importer \
    s3  --region eu-west-1 sync s3://path-to-s3-folder ${incomming}


count=0
echo ""
echo "Searching for zip files in ${incomming} folder"
for f in `find ${incomming} -name '*.zip'`;
do
  echo "\n${count}: ${f} --------------------"
  count=$((count+1))
  name=`basename "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  dir=`dirname "$f"`
  if [  -d "${dir}/${name}" ]; then
echo "\tWarning: directory "${dir}/${name}" already exist for file: ${f} ... - skipping - not imported"
     continue
  fi
```

Comment: "I can't produce anymore keys-aws quota/user." I have no idea what you are trying to say here. It sounds like the AWS key you are using has been deleted or something. Try logging into IAM console and verifying that it is an active key.

Comment: @MarkB has a point, since this is a credentials problem, you'll probably won't get far without access to AWS's IAM section. If you don't have permission to view and change this, find someone with suitable permissions and get him to help you. The most important part is to check if AWS is accepting your credentials, and if not - creating a fresh set of credentials and updating the config file.

Comment: I have checked in IAM console, the keys are active. I'll try to delete them and regenerate, Then I'll update. I too, believe it's something with credentials, just don't know what exactly yet